# Null Pointer Exception in my Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When I call this Activity, a Null Pointer Exception occurs. Why does this happen?

```
package com.andrd.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class User_Detail_ListActivity extends Activity{
TransportData tdata;
private TextView drivernametxt,agetxt,addresstxt,liecencetxt,contactNotxt,driverTypetxt,truckNotxt,truckPermittxt,truckTypetxt,fromtxt,totxt;
Button editBtn,deleteBtn,cancelBtn;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);


    drivernametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    agetxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ageTextView);
    addresstxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
    liecencetxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.licenseNoTextView);
    contactNotxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactNoTextView);
    driverTypetxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.employmetnTypeTextView);
    truckNotxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.truckNoTextView);
    truckPermittxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.truckPermitTextView);
    truckPermittxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.truckTypeTextView);
    fromtxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromTextView);
    totxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.toTextView);

    editBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
    deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

    drivernametxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("DriverName"));
    agetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Age"));
    addresstxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Address"));
    liecencetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("LiecenseNo"));

    contactNotxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ContactNo"));
    driverTypetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("DriverType"));
    truckNotxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckNo"));
    truckPermittxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckPermit"));
    truckTypetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckType"));
    fromtxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("FromLocation"));
    totxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ToLocation"));


    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(User_Detail_ListActivity.this, EditUserDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TruckNo", getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckNo"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                tdata.deleteUser(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckNo"));
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "database Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });

    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: paste the stacktrace or at least tell us which line is throwing the exception please.

Comment: why your never accept answers....

Comment: 04-01 09:12:20.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andrd.gps/com.andrd.gps.User_Detail_ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Mukesh:Please edit your post & paste the stack trace there.In this one can't able to understand at which line NullPointerException occurred.

Comment: Can you post the code for the onCreate method of the Activity you are trying to start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you add the activity to you Application Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".EditUserDetailActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Java the reasons for NullPointerException is:

1. you accessed the uninitialized variables.

But in this case you may not set the Extras in the previous Activity or your getString() method argument value maybe wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mukesh I thing you made a mistake in initializing the TextView.

Please check that you have initialized `truckPermittxt` twice. Initialize `truckTypetxt` there & then try using `truckTypetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckType"));`

This main reason of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You never  initialized `truckTypetxt`... You instead initialized this one twice.

```
truckPermittxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.truckPermitTextView);
truckPermittxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.truckTypeTextView);
```

But yet you use `truckTypetxt`

```
truckTypetxt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TruckType"));
```